# canvas.toDataURL() - For bigger canvas-image

Tags: image, canvas, charts, html5-canvas, todataurl

I would like to two show a Chart and **also** present an url with a link to a bigger Chart. The small preview-image looks and works fine:

```
<canvas id="image"></canvas>

var ct1 = document.getElementById("image").getContext("2d");
ct1.canvas.width = document.getElementById("image").offsetWidth;
ct1.canvas.height = document.getElementById("image").offsetHeight;
var Chart1  = new Chart(ct1).Line(lineChartData1,options);
```

The canvas is wrapped in a div, that's why *offsetWidth* and *offsetHeight* (to fill this additional div-element). Cause of the responsive-design there is no fixed image. Anyway, this works perfectly. For the URL to the "bigger" image I want to have the URL. I know the **toDataURL()** will help.

```
var url = document.getElementById("image").toDataURL();
document.write(url);
```

There are two disturbing problems with it:

1. The URL with this way exisists and, but the image has no content.
2. I also want to give the canvas-image a new size, like I managed with *ct1.canvas.width* and *ct1.canvas.height*, but it seems I cannot add this to the *toDataURL*.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it. **Chart.js** is animating the charts, so the toDataURL() I mentioned in my first question rendered only an empty image. We have to initiate the toDataURL, not before the animation is done. We handle that with the options:

```
var options = { 
onAnimationComplete: done
}
```

and a tiny function:

```
function done() {
console.log('done');
var url=document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL();
document.getElementById("canvas_link").href=url;
}
```

I think that's all.